# Which, if any, colored cards can be made colorless after being cast?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Which, if any, colored cards can be made colorless after being cast?

I'm not interested in cards that use some factor to determine color at moment of casting (such as Devoid).

Comment: Care to share why you are interested in doing this?

Comment: @John - Got inspired by the question on Prismatic Lace: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/53414/can-i-select-zero-colors-for-prismatic-lace

Comment: I have cleared out the conversation about whether Magic: the Gathering is on topic on this site. Community consensus on that decision is already well established. If you would like more information about what is on topic here, please see the [help/on-topic]. If you would like clarification, or to request/suggest a change to the rules, or you believe the rules have been applied incorrectly, you should ask a question on [meta].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No spell has an inherent way to become colorless after it has been cast while it's still on stack. There are ways to do this however, but it requires using other cards. This means that almost all spells can be made colorless, the only ones that can't are spells that can't be targeted or prevent using the stack until they resolve (split second).

1. Change target spell to colorless:

   - [Ersatz Gnomes](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bErsatz%20Gnomes%5d) is an artifact creature that a tap ability to turn a targeted spell on the stack colorless.
   - [Moonlace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMoonlace%5d) is a one cost blue spell that will turn a target spell on the stack colorless.
2. Permanents that change themselves to colorless. (all red creatures)

   - [Ancient Kavu](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAncient%20Kavu%5d) 2 cost activated ability to turn itself colorless.
   - [Blazing Blade Askari](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlazing%20Blade%20Askari%5d) 2 cost activated ability to turn itself colorless.
   - [Raging Spirit](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRaging%20Spirit%5d) 2 cost activated ability to turn itself colorless.
3. Turns another permanent colorless.

   - Ersatz Gnomes has a second tap ability to turn a targeted permanent colorless until end of turn.
   - Moonlace can also target a permanent to turn it colorless. This effect is permanent.
   - [Xathrid Gorgon](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bXathrid%20Gorgon%5d) is a black creature that has a tap ability costing 3 mana that will permanently turn a target creature into a colorless artifact and gives it defender (flavored turn to stone gorgon ability).
4. Change everything to colorless.

   - [Thran Lens](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThran%20Lens%5d) this 2 cost artifact makes all permanents colorless, this applies to all permanents controlled by all players.
   - [Mycosynth Lattice](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMycosynth%20Lattice%5d) this changes everything to colorless, in play, on the stack, in the hand, in the deck, etc.
   - [Ghostflame Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGhostflame%20Sliver%5d) this 2 cost black and red creature doesn't apply to everything, but it applies to all slivers, regardless of who controls them.

Comment: So, if I'm reading this right, there's no way to change creatures to colorless permanently, and still have it be useful. Unless there's a way to un-disable a Gorgon target and remove its Defender?

Comment: @Malady there are ways to let a creature with defender attack, like Aracdes, the Strategist, I also doublechecked moonlace and it is permanent. I'm editing the answer now that I understand your question better.

Comment: Thanks! ... Doesn't Mycosynth Lattice *not* apply to things on the battlefield?

Comment: @Malady "All [,..] permanents are colorless" the only place something is called a permanent is when it is on the battlefield. Lattice applys everywhere. It also makes those permanents into artifacts.

Comment: I have cleared out the conversation about whether Magic: the Gathering is on topic on this site. Community consensus on that decision is already well established. If you would like more information about what is on topic here, please see the [help/on-topic]. If you would like clarification, or to request/suggest a change to the rules, or you believe the rules have been applied incorrectly, you should ask a question on [meta].